# using zed camera with ros?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i am trying to use the zed camera with ros and i used this tutorial "https://www.stereolabs.com/blog/index.php/2015/09/07/use-your-zed-camera-with-ros/"
but i have these errors

```
CMake Warning at /opt/ros/indigo/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:76 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "image_transport"
  with any of the following names:

    image_transportConfig.cmake
    image_transport-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "image_transport" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or
  set "image_transport_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.
  If "image_transport" provides a separate development package or SDK, be
  sure it has been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  zed-ros-wrapper/CMakeLists.txt:30 (find_package)


-- Could not find the required component 'image_transport'. The following CMake error indicates that you either need to install the package with the same name or change your environment so that it can be found.
CMake Error at /opt/ros/indigo/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:83 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "image_transport"
  with any of the following names:

    image_transportConfig.cmake
    image_transport-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "image_transport" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or
  set "image_transport_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.
  If "image_transport" provides a separate development package or SDK, be
  sure it has been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  zed-ros-wrapper/CMakeLists.txt:30 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/ubuntu/catkin_WS/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/ubuntu/catkin_WS/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
make: *** [cmake_check_build_system] Error 1
Invoking "make cmake_check_build_system" failed
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/239423/using-zed-camera-with-ros?/) by [safaa samy](https://answers.ros.org/users/27478/safaa-samy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-07-13

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2018-01-05**:
I remember having some issues with openCV 3 dependencies when I first got the Zed camera working in my setup. I can't remember exactly how I got around them, but the cv_bridge package sticks in my memory. I'll see if I can find how I fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello Safaa,

I am using the ZED with my Jetson TX1 since a while now. When you follow the tutorial, make sure you install the dependencies listed:

- roscpp
- rosconsole
- sensor_msgs
- opencv2
- cv_bridge
- image_transport

If these are ROS packages these can be installed via your systems package manager. EG on ubuntu you can run:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-DISTRO-roscpp ros-DISTRO-rosconsole ros-DISTRO-sensor-msgs ros-DISTRO-cv-bridge ros-DISTRO-image-transport
```

Be sure to replace **DISTRO** with your ROS distribution, eg **indigo** or **kinetic**. By the looks of it you are missing:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-DISTRO-image-transport
```

---

Originally posted by [NZNobody](https://answers.ros.org/users/27466/nznobody/) with karma: 156 on 2016-07-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [abdelkrim](https://answers.ros.org/users/29601/abdelkrim/) on 2018-01-05**:
@NZNobody  i get the some error   i pu it here
https://answers.ros.org/question/278894/zed-ros-camera-installation-issues/